# Loading jquery.inputmask using Systemjs, Jspm and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, systemjs, jspm, jquery-inputmask

I am using TypeScript 2.0 with a Systemjs dependency loader. I am trying to use the jquery.inputmask plugin along with several other of that caliber. The problem is I can not find the correct way to import the plugin. I used jspm to install in hopes that the connections where correct. I am not sure if I am just importing it wrong or there is a setup issue. I have tried the following:

## 1 -- Doesnt work

```
meta: {
    "jquery.inputmask": {
        "format": "global",
        "deps": ["jquery"]
    }
}
```

## 2 -- Doesnt Work

```
meta: {
    "jspm_packages/npm/jquery.inputmask@3.3.1/dist/": {
        globals: {
            "jquery": "jquery"
        }
    }
}
```

## jspm made 2 Entries for it

```
"jquery.inputmask": "npm:jquery.inputmask@3.3.1",
```

and

```
"npm:jquery.inputmask@3.3.1": {
  "jquery": "npm:jquery@2.2.4",
  "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2"
},
```

Can anyone show me how to correct whatever the issues is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone was wondering. It took me all night but i finally got it working with the following changes in my config.js file.

```
packages: {
    'jquery.inputmask': {
        main: '/dist/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.js',
        // format: 'global',
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        map: {
            'jquery': 'npm:jquery@3.1.0/dist/jquery.js',
        },
        meta: {
            'jauery.inputmask': {
                deps: ['jquery'],
                exports: '$'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that helps to someone.